# Glassfish generates ProcessorTask exception and hangs

Tags: java, glassfish, grizzly

After some time Glassfish 3.1.2 start Processor Task Exception and it stopped working.

Following is the stacktrace:

---

```
SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|com.sun.grizzly.config.GrizzlyServiceListener|_ThreadID=24;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|GRIZZLY0051: ProcessorTask exception.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.Buffer.checkBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.InputReader.read(InputReader.java:216)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpInputBuffer.ensureAvailable(AjpInputBuffer.java:210)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpInputBuffer.readAjpMessageHeader(AjpInputBuffer.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ajp.AjpProcessorTask.parseRequest(AjpProcessorTask.java:97)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:706)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please download glassfish 3.1.2.2 and apply this patch [1].

[1] https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7319744/grizzly-gf3122-patch.zip

Comment: What that patch is for? Do you have any reference of this issue?

Comment: This is not official patch I maintain to backport known Grizzly related Glassfish fixes to Glassfish 3.1.2.2.